# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{\coth(s)}{s^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, hyperbolic-functions, inverse-laplace

I found this problem and I have been trying to solve it without success. Find inverse Laplace transform of function $F:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ given as:
$$F(s)=\frac{\coth(s)}{s^2}$$
using complex analysis. I tried solving this using residue which says that
$$f(t)=\sum \text{Res} F(s) e^{(st)}$$
but I get that $s=0$ is pole of third order and it gets complicated and with much derivation. I know that I can use contour integration but again I have to solve this residue problem. I am wondering if there is any more elegant solution or if my way is the only way to solve this?